# Error when placing markers at specific points using matplotlib and markevery

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to place markers on a line specific points. I have a TRUE/FALSE list that says where on the x-axis the markers are wanted. Here is the snippet I am using:

```
markers_on = list(compress(self.x, self.titanic1))
a0.plot(self.x, self.nya, marker='v', markevery=markers_on)
```

self.titanic1 is a list of Boolean values, self.x is a list of our x axis values and self.nya is a list of y values. I get the following error message.

[image: error message]

The interesting bit is that the list in the error message is correct, those are the correct x-axis values for the markers. Does anybody know what this message means? The markevery doc clearly says it'll take a list of integers.

```
markevery   [None | int | length-2 tuple of int | slice | list/array of int | float | length-2 tuple of float]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `compress`?

Comment: The compress strips out out the x-values where the matching self.titanic value is true. You can see the resulting list in the error message.

Comment: It's the fact it complains about fancy indexing specifically. Lists don't support that (unless it's a catch-all error) so I'm wondering why you get the error you do if it can apparently take lists as an input.

Answer (score 2):

If the list supplied to `markevery` is a list of integers, it is interpreted as a list of **indices** of the values to mark.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,1,0.2)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

boolean= [True, False, False, True, True]
mark = list(np.arange(len(x))[boolean])

plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", markevery=mark)

plt.show()
```

However, note that you may directly supply a list of **booleans** to the `markevery`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,1,0.2)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

boolean= [True, False, False, True, True]

plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", markevery=boolean)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out a work around to plot just the markers. (I plot the line earlier.)

```
markers_x = list(compress(self.x, self.titanic1))
markers_y = list(compress(self.nya, self.titanic1))
markers_y = [i * 1.01 for i in markers_y] # shift the markers up a bit
t1, = a0.plot(markers_x, markers_y, 'bv') # pass t1 later for legend
```

But I'd still like to know what that error message means if anyone has a clue or a trailhead.